# How do I check for duplicate answers in this array? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

Sorry for the newbie question. Could someone help me out? Simple array here. What's the best/easiest method to check all the user input is unique and not duplicated? Thanks

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] Numbers = new string[5];


        Numbers[0] = txtNumber1.Text;
        Numbers[1] = txtNumber2.Text;
        Numbers[2] = txtNumber3.Text;
        Numbers[3] = txtNumber4.Text;
        Numbers[4] = txtNumber5.Text;


        foreach (string Result in Numbers)
        {
            lbNumbers.Items.Add(Result);
        }

        txtNumber1.Clear();
        txtNumber2.Clear();
        txtNumber3.Clear();
        txtNumber4.Clear();
        txtNumber5.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

I should have added I need to check to happen before the numbers are output. Thanks

Comment: The answers below show you how to check after you have added them to lbNumbers.Items. you could also check as you add them in you foreach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One simple approach is via LINQ:

```
bool allUnique = Numbers.Distinct().Count() == Numbers.Length;
```

Comment: Hi. I used this and it always returns as false. Did I use it wrong?

Comment: What I mean is, i set this up then added if (allUnique == true) then it displays, if not then it pops up a message asking for unique numbers. Is this not the correct way to use this?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using a `HashSet<string>`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(Numbers);
if (set.Count == Numbers.Count)
{ 
    // all unique
}
```

or with `Enumerable.All`:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
// HashSet.Add returns a bool if the item was added because it was unique
bool allUnique = Numbers.All(text=> set.Add(text));
```

[`Enunmerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) is more efficient when the sequence is very large since it does not create the set completely but one after each other and will return `false` as soon as it detects a duplicate.

Here's a demo of this effect: http://ideone.com/G48CYv

- `HashSet` constructor memory consumption: 50 MB, duration: 00:00:00.2962615
- `Enumerable.All` memory consumption: 0 MB, duration:       00:00:00.0004254

msdn

> The [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class provides high-performance set operations.
>   A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose
>   elements are in no particular order.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, in my opinion, would be to **insert all values inside a set** and then **check if its size is equal to the array's size**. A set can't contain duplicate values, so if any value is duplicate, it won't be inserted into the set.

This is also OK in complexity if you don't have millions of values, because insertion in a set is done in `O(logn)` time, so total check time will be `O(nlogn)`.

If you want something optimal in complexity, you can do this in `O(n)` time by going through the array, and **putting each value found into a hash map** while incrementing its value: if value doesn't exist in set, you add it with count = 1. If it does exist, you increment its count. 
Then, you **go through the hash map and check that all values have a count of one**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to make sure that your listbox doesn't have dups then use this:

```
if(!lbNumbers.Items.Contains(Result))    
    lbNumbers.Items.Add(Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public bool arrayContainsDuplicates(string[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 2; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length - 1; j++) {
      if (array[i] == array[j]) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Warning if anyone use this code: its result is invalid and my attempt to correct it was rejected (reason given: my "edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner").